# Using python i am trying to submit data to a website via requests. How to pass the confirmation dialog?

Tags: python, authentication, dialog, python-requests, confirm

I am logging into a site using Python and Requests. Upon logging in there is a .asp page lets say import.asp where I am sending some data (via POST) using Requests again. Once this data is sent and submitted there is a popup asking me to confirm if I want to proceed ahead. I want to click the 'OK' button.

I have tried Selenium and I keep getting 'element not found' error. I think I am not choosing the proper elements.

## My Python code

```
url1 = "hxxp://site.com/login.asp"
url2 = "hxxp://site.com/import.asp" 

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

payload1 = {'username': 'abc','password': '123'}
payload2 = {'signature':sig_test,informational':'off','comment':'testing333'}

s = requests.Session()      

#Logging in
r = s.post(url1, data=payload, headers=headers)

#Posting data
r2 = s.post(url2, json.dumps(payload2), headers=headers)
```

## HTML code of the receiving app - javascript

```
<script>
function confirmSubmit()
{
var agree=confirm("Are you sure you wish to continue?");
if (agree)
    return true ;
else
    return false ;
}
</script>
```

## HTML code of the receiving app - html content

```
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="import.asp" onsubmit="document.myform.data.value=escape(document.myform.data.value);return confirmSubmit();"/>

<label><b>Signature:</b></label><br />
<textarea name="signature" cols="85" rows="10"></textarea><br>
<label><b>Comment:</b></label><br />
<textarea name="comment" cols="85" rows="10"></textarea><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="informational"> Info
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Import Signatures">
</form>
```

I expect the data to pass through and give me confirmation which I receive when I actually do this on the website.

Comment: 1. There's a `'` missing in your Python code. 2. Most of your JavaScript function is unnecessary. Could be just `return confirm(...);`

Comment: I am actually trying to automate the process using python. The HTML code you see is for an already existing web application that allows you to add a signature, I want to automate it using python. What would be a better solution for python along with requests to interact with javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using requests you aren't going to be interacting with any javascript. The code that you show doesn't seem to indicate anything meaningful to you happens when yes is clicked anyway. Use developer tools in chrome or firefox to manually log into the website and inspect all of the requests that are actually sent to the server. If you duplicate them you should be able to get in. The javascript is only used in the creation of these requests unless there is something more complicated like a websocket which there doesn't seem to be.